# SQL Query - Getting the SupplierName with the ID of a Min() of a Count()

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

I'm testing a query in this DataBase:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_count

I'm trying to find out the name of the Supplier with the less Products.

Product table:

```
ProductID | ProductName | SupplierID | CategoryID | Unit| Price
```

Supplier table:

```
SupplierID | SupplierName | ContactName | AddressCity | PostalCode | Country | Phone
```

So far I just got the SupplierID, which is 10, but I'm having trouble completing the query so it can return the SupplierName of that ID.

```
SELECT SupplierID AS SupID, min(MinSuppPrice)
FROM (
SELECT P.SupplierID, count(P.Price) MinSuppPrice
FROM Products P
group by P.SupplierID
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an anwser for my query "Find the name of the Supplier with the less Products." (and SupplierID)

```
SELECT S.SupplierID, S.SupplierName
FROM  Suppliers S, Products P
WHERE S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID 
GROUP BY S.SupplierID, S.SupplierName
HAVING COUNT(P.ProductID) = (
    SELECT MIN (ProdCounter) 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(P.ProductID) AS ProdCounter
        FROM Products P
        GROUP BY P.SupplierID
    )
);
```

The result is:

```
SupplierID | SupplierName
10           Refrescos Americanas LTDA
13           Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH
27           Escargots Nouveaux
```

(They only have 1 product in Products table)

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses analytic functions:

```
SELECT SupplierID AS SupID, NumProducts
FROM (SELECT P.SupplierID, COUNT(*) as NumProducts,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Products P
      GROUP BY P.SupplierID
     ) p
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew about that. But in my scenario I can't use those functions. (I'm studying for an exam and that anwser isn't in the lectured program).